# Datomic in-memory query in Java returns no results

Tags: java, clojure, datomic

Posting this on Clojure Google support group doesn't seem to work for me, so I will try asking here.

I'm running the following slightly modified GettingStarted.java (from clojure distro) as a Spring-configured test to see how Datomic could be integrated into my app and getting no results on the very first Peer.q call down below (whereas identical console call returns 150 records).  What am I doing wrong here, please help?

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={GettingStartedConfig.class}, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class GettingStartedTest {



    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    private String uri = "datomic:mem://seattle";

    @Autowired
    private Reader schema;

    @Autowired
    private Reader seed0;

    private  void pause() {
        if (System.getProperty("NOPAUSE") == null) {
            log.info("\nPress enter to continue...");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {


        log.info("Creating and connecting to database...at {}", uri +"\n\n");


        Peer.createDatabase(uri);
        Connection conn = Peer.connect(uri);

        pause();


        log.info("Parsing schema dtm file and running transaction...\n\n");


        log.info("schema: "+schema);

        List schema_tx = (List) Util.readAll(schema).get(0);
        schema.close();
        Object txResult = conn.transact(schema_tx).get();
        log.info("result of schema transaction: "+txResult);

        pause();

        log.info("Parsing seed data dtm file and running transaction...\n\n");

        List data_tx = (List) Util.readAll(seed0).get(0);
        seed0.close();
        txResult = conn.transact(data_tx).get();

        pause();

        log.info("Finding all communities, counting results...\n\n");

        Collection results = Peer.q("[:find ?c :where [?c :community/name]]", conn.db());
        log.info("size of the result = {} " , results.size() + "\n\n");

        pause();
```

...............................

> [main] INFO
>   com.excelsiorsoft.daedalus.persistence.datomic.GettingStartedTest -
>   Finding all communities, counting results...
>
> [main] INFO
>   com.excelsiorsoft.daedalus.persistence.datomic.GettingStartedTest -
>   size of the result = 0

Thanks in advance for giving me a hand.

Comment: Such forum indeed exists, and I made an attempt to ask there as well prior to posting here but my inquiry there doesn't get accepted.

Comment: In that case, I wish you luck. :)

Comment: Did you make sure the autowired got something in it instead of null? Also if the autowired got something in it... is it valid? After the seed, you should get some value return if it read it in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't debug your code for you.

But I would suspect that you aren't actually populating the database in the first place. This might be something to do with the Spring configuration, or with whatever code you are using to read the data in.

I suggest trying a simpler test where you directly insert one or two facts, and test that you can read them before trying anything more complex.